# Upload form inside Drupal block

Tags: forms, csv, drupal, upload, block

I wish to make an upload form **inside a Drupal block** (with PHP-code enabled) and I wish the validation / treatment to be on the same block.

All I have found are either PHP specific code (creating a form and redirect to an 'upload.php' page) or Drupal module code (upload.inc with functions to create, submit and validate the form)...

What should I do?

Comment: Even though Drupal will allow to do that but that will not be a best practice. Instead of that - I recommend that you make use of WEBFORM module. Once you create the webform then it will get that form in the form of `block` and then you may position that block anywhere onto the page.

Answer (score 0):

There is the [advanced block module](https://www.drupal.org/project/afb) that can help you place form inside a block. Could also try the [form block module](http://drupal.org/project/formblock) if that works for this situation depending on what the upload is for.

Custom Module:
This can also be easily done via custom module. As this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5271485) recommends

```
function yourmodule_block_view($delta='')
{
  switch($delta) {
    case 'your_block_name':
      $block['subject'] = null; // Most forms don't have a subject 
      $block['content'] = drupal_get_form('yourmodule_form_function');
      break;
   }
   return $block;
 }
```

the form array returned by `drupal_get_form` will be automatically rendered.

`yourmodule_form_function` is a function (in your module or an existing Drupal module) that returns the form array;